# allowing user to cast one vote anonymously with GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I have a GAE app for voting, where each voter is sent a unique key via email and then uses that key to vote at a web page.  I'd like to ensure that each voter can only cast one vote, and also that the vote remains anonymous.

I have a `Voter` class with an attribute `has_voted` and a `Vote` class with an attribute for the vote. I want the votes to be anonymous so I don't want one to be a parent of the other.

I tried updating both using a transaction, e.g.,

```
def put_vote_transaction(vkey, vote):
    voter = Voter.get(vkey)
    if voter.has_voted:
        return False
    else:
        voter.has_voted = True
        db.put([voter, vote])
        return True
```

but this doesn't work because the voter and vote are in different entity groups.

How can I ensure that each voter can cast only one vote but keep that one vote anonymous?

Answer (score 1):

As you observed, since `voter` and `vote` are in separate entity groups you cannot update them in the same transaction.  However, you can update `voter` in the transaction (as you are now), and record their `vote` in a [transactional task](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html#Tasks_Within_Transactions) associated with this transaction.

Comment: This seems to get part of the way there, but it seems: (1) tasks may (rarely) be executed more than once so I'd need to include a UUID, and (2) tasks may (rarely) fail to get executed and raise an exception causing a vote to get lost.

Comment: #1: Yes, you should pre-allocate a key for your `vote` entity just in case the task runs twice (you can use [`db.allocate_ids`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html#allocate_ids) to get a unique ID).

Comment: #2: Transactional tasks are guaranteed to be enqueued if and only if your transaction commits.  The datastore operation in the task may fail (due to a transient error) - but even in this your task will automatically retry until it succeeds.  You will not lose votes.

Answer (score 1):

You could assign the vote item to the voter when they are created for them to later 'spend' on their voting. And you could use a single property to link both the votes->voters and votes->thingToVoteOn (polymorphic) to get around the transaction issues. I'll try to illustrate:

If your Vote model was like:

```
Vote(db.Model):
    assigned_to = db.ReferenceProperty(collection_name='votes')
```

And assuming you have some other model for the item you are voting on like:

```
ThingToVoteOn(db.Model):
    pass
```

And if when you first create a Voter you assign them a Vote

```
Voter(db.Model):
    # your voter properties

voter = Voter()
voter.put()
vote_to_spend = Vote()
vote_to_spend.assigned_to = voter()
vote_to_spend.put()
```

Then later the Voter can 'spend' this vote by having it reassigned to the entity they are voting for:

```
vote = voter.vote
vote.assigned_to = thing_you_vote_on
vote.put()
```

As soon as the vote is 'cast' it will no longer be assigned to the voter (so is completely anonymous), and it always takes place within the same transaction as it is only a single entity (`Vote`) being stored at the time of voting.

Comment: This works well if there is only a single question to vote on.  But what if there are multiple questions?  With this scheme, a `Voter` has voted if there is no `Vote` entity assigned to them.  Thus we would need to pre-allocate the `Vote` entities for all existing users whenever a question was created, and pre-allocate `Vote` entities for all existing questions when a new `Voter` is created (both could be expensive if the number of voters or questions is not small).